# Links no longer formatted prettifully

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When you post a link in chat that is suppose to be formatted nicely (StackOverflow Question, Amazon Link, etc), it no longer converts it to something prettiful.

Sometimes it times out and asks me to retry. Other times it just never reformats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means API is having temporary availability issues. I don't think it's happening any more.

Comment: It happened exactly 6 minutes ago in the Gaming chatroom

Comment: @Juan We don't like Gamers. They smell funny. :P